# Why won't Sage compile my code?

Tags: cython, sage

Sage is supposed to be able to create compiled code using Cython. I have never been able to get this to work. The problem appears to be with my Sage installation, since compiling fails on the included example. I don't believe I did anything special during installation, but apparently I something wrong. The [Sage tutorial](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/programming.html) says

> In order to make your own compiled Sage code, give the file an .spyx extension (instead of .sage). If you are working with the command-line interface, you can attach and load compiled code exactly like with interpreted code (at the moment, attaching and loading Cython code is not supported with the notebook interface). The actual compilation is done “behind the scenes” without your having to do anything explicit. See $SAGE_ROOT/examples/programming/sagex/factorial.spyx for an example of a compiled implementation of the factorial function that directly uses the GMP C library. To try this out for yourself, cd to $SAGE_ROOT/examples/programming/sagex/, then do the following:

```
sage: load "factorial.spyx"
```

When I try I get the following message:

> Compiling ./factorial.spyx...
>   Error compiling cython file:
>   Error compiling ./factorial.spyx:
>   running build
>   running build_ext
>   building '_home_oliver_Desktop_sage_4_7_1_linux_32bit_ubuntu_10_04_lts_i686_Linux_examples_programming_sagex_factorial_spyx_0' extension
>   creating build
>   creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6
>   gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/oliver/Desktop/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/include/csage/ -I/home/oliver/Desktop/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/include/ -I/home/oliver/Desktop/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/include/python2.6/ -I/home/oliver/Desktop/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/oliver/Desktop/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/devel/sage/sage/ext/ -I/home/oliver/Desktop/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/devel/sage/ -I/home/oliver/Desktop/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/devel/sage/sage/gsl/ -I. -I/home/oliver/Desktop/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local/include/python2.6 -c _home_oliver_Desktop_sage_4_7_1_linux_32bit_ubuntu_10_04_lts_i686_Linux_examples_programming_sagex_factorial_spyx_0.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/_home_oliver_Desktop_sage_4_7_1_linux_32bit_ubuntu_10_04_lts_i686_Linux_examples_programming_sagex_factorial_spyx_0.o -w -O2
>   creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6
>   gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/_home_oliver_Desktop_sage_4_7_1_linux_32bit_ubuntu_10_04_lts_i686_Linux_examples_programming_sagex_factorial_spyx_0.o -L/home/oliver/Desktop/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local//lib/ -L/home/wstein/build/sage-4.7.1/local/lib -lmpfr -lgmp -lgmpxx -lstdc++ -lpari -lm -lcurvesntl -lg0nntl -ljcntl -lrankntl -lgsl -lgslcblas -latlas -lntl -lcsage -lpython2.6 -o build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/_home_oliver_Desktop_sage_4_7_1_linux_32bit_ubuntu_10_04_lts_i686_Linux_examples_programming_sagex_factorial_spyx_0.so -L/home/oliver/Desktop/sage-4.7.1-linux-32bit-ubuntu_10.04_lts-i686-Linux/local//lib
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++ collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: (1) Can you ordinarily compile c++ code invoking -lstdc++?  (2) /home/wstein/ shouldn't be on the path, but I usually work with source builds which do some repointing.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I needed to hear. I reinstalled g++-multilib, and now it works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Two notes: first, you can write your comment as an answer and accept it.  Second, you can often get more specific Sage help at ask.sagemath.org, where a fair number of the developers hang out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per DSM's comment, I reinstalled g++-multilib, and now everything works fine.